# Ubuntu not recognising Wi-Fi card on desktop

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek-wireless

I have a desktop with Asus P6X58D motherboard and Realtek RTL8811 AU Wireless LAN card. It is now dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have no LAN and rely on chaining to iPad.

The card is working correctly when booted into Windows but the adaptor isn't being recognised in Ubuntu. It worked correctly last time I had Windows 10 and Ubuntu LTS 16 loaded.

Any ideas on how to make Ubuntu 20.04 LTS recognise the existence of the card?

Comment: You need to install a driver. Search for this device for a solution. Most likely `rtl8812au-dkms` will do. If not USB ids are needed.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and not too sure how to download when I find a driver.  I cannot connect in Ubuntu and would have to download the driver in Windows.  Can I copy the driver to USB stick for transfer to Ubuntu?

Comment: You can find detailed instructions at this site. But the driver I mentioned is installed by `sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms`.

Comment: Will that work from USB stick?

Comment: You can always connect to internet by your phone connected to USB.

Comment: Thank you Pilot6, USB connection worked straight away.  I didn't realise that was possible.  Simpler than Wi Fi.